# Vuetify.js shaped card being overridden by v-sheet

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following card component:

```
<template>
  <v-card
    outlined
    shaped
    :class="{
      broadcaster: chatMessage.user.isBroadcaster,
      subscriber: chatMessage.user.isSubscriber,
      moderator: chatMessage.user.isModerator
    }"
  >
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-avatar size="50" color="grey">
        <v-img
          height="50"
          width="50"
          :src="chatMessage.user.profileImageUrl"
        ></v-img>
      </v-list-item-avatar>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-card-text>
          <DisplayText
            :emotes="chatMessage.emotes"
            :message="chatMessage.message"
          />
        </v-card-text>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">
          {{ chatMessage.user.displayName }}
        </v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Note that the card is styled with **outlined** and **shaped** which should give a nice offset rounded corners. In devtools you can clearly see the shaped style getting overridden by the sheet style.

The output is not shaped though as shown in this screenshot.

[image: Firefox Dev Tools Screenshot]

I am not clear where this sheet style is even coming from. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you create an example on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Yeah working on it now.

Comment: On your screenshot, the card seems to have 4px border-radius as ad defined in your `.v-sheet` class, what do you expect to have?

Comment: It looks like in the Vuetify [source code for V-Card](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VCard/VCard.ts) (line 52), the v-sheet class is included, so that's where it's coming from. Doesn't actually answer your question about how to fix it though, sorry

Comment: Tried to reproduce in a codepen and am not having the same issue. There is something specific to what I am doing in my app.

https://codepen.io/notmyself/pen/RwPMWNN

Comment: Please add the chatMessage.user classes to the codepen.

Comment: Add `style="border-radius: 16px;"` into `v-card`, as workaround